# IE link click redirecting issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Here is my code:

```
<a id="testBtn" class="test-btn" title="Test" href="https://www.google.com" data-id="loader"><b>Test</b><small>Test Click</small></a>
```

When I try to click this link, It's redirecting to https://:0/ in IE. But other browsers its working fine. What is the issue here?

Comment: There's no way your link is doing that by itself.  Or, your IE is broken.

Comment: What’s `data-id="loader"`? I imagine it’s a JavaScript that’s doing something wrong. Can you post the JS for this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems to be working fine. Did you try to access that url in internet explorer directly? It might be a problem with internet explorer redirecting https://www.google.com to  https://:0/ .

Answer (score 0):

The code works well on my side (in IE 11). Try to use F12 developer tools to check the document elements, verify whether the url is changed, Also you could try [resetting the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) or re-install the IE browser.